# PQgetisnull : Not not return true even value is empty in DB

Tags: postgresql

I am working on bug in my Database library which use LibPQ internally.I see following behavior which looks strange to me :

For  postgreSql Datatype `DATE` it returns true if its empty in DB
For postgreSql Datatype  `TIME` it return true if its empty in DB

But for VARCHAR,SMALLINT..it return false even they were empty in DB.

PS. I have not check for other data types yet

Comment: What you mean by "empty"? A DATE or TIME field can only hold valid dates or times or it can be NULL (of allowed by its definition). So are they NULL or not?

Comment: I analyzed code in Deep, I found that , My Database library except DATA & TIME updates NULL , If they are empty..But in case of other values..it used char[] staring to update values..if values are empty it might be inserting null terminates string...rather than a null...
Thanks for Your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The empty string and zero (0) are NOT the same thing as NULL.  Run a form of this query to see how many NULLs vs empty strings exist for your field:

```
SELECT COALESCE(<field_name>,'NULL'), COUNT(*)
FROM <table_name>
WHERE <field_name> = ''
   OR <field_name> IS NULL
GROUP BY 1
```

Replace the empty string ('') in this query with zero to check against numeric fields.